# How to play video inline with WkWebView

Tags: iphone, swift, video, wkwebview

When you use an iphone and play video in a webview, this video is open in the native player in fullscreen.

We have tried UIWebView and WKWebView with "allowsInlineMediaPlayback" property to true. But the video in the web content launch in fullscreen with an iphone iOS 10.2. Have you and idea what i can do ?

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
// Fix Fullscreen mode for video and autoplay
webConfiguration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
webConfiguration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.backgroundView.frame.width, height:self.backgroundView.frame.height), configuration: webConfiguration)
```

Env : Xcode 8, swift 3

Comment: Hi. Did you get answer for this?

Answer (score 26):

There is no problem for your code,but you need one more step, the video `URL` you use should always with a parameter `playsinline=1`.

```
//step1
if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: "https://somevideo.mp4?playsinline=1")
//step2
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

then you can do the left things.

Comment: step1 could also be done by setting the script of your web video

Comment: dont forget you may require mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

Answer (score 21):

**Here is a solution as you want, i make player programatically and change some code, to play video inline.**

```
var myPlayer: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

        myPlayer = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 300), configuration: webConfiguration)
        self.view.addSubview(myPlayer)

        if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9n1e1N0Sa9k?playsinline=1") {
             let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: videoURL)
             myPlayer.load(request)
        }

        //OR to show player control also, use this
        /*if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9n1e1N0Sa9k?playsinline=1&controls=1") {
             let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: videoURL)
             myPlayer.load(request)
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Note that if your WKWebView is initialized via a storyboard, you will have to check the "Inline Playback" box in that element's attribute's inspector instead of passing in a WKWebViewConfiguration programmatically.

Comment: @Hardik
How can I get notified when media play or pause ?

Comment: You need to play video in WKWebView ? or you are looking for youtube player ?

Answer (score 8):

I ended up doing so:

```
func load(url: String) {
    let html = "<video playsinline controls width=\"100%\" src=\"\(url)\"> </video>"
    self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Load web view as HTML and add some video tags to customise the UX.

Comment: That's what actually worked for me too. But I did include:
`<body style="margin: 0px; background-color: black;"> <video ...> ...</head> </body>`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
   configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
}
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
let webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best way to do it without needing an HTML string. Also added a test video that's hosted on archive.org so you can avoid the big buck bunny test video horror show:

Swift 4:

```
if let mediaURL:URL = URL(string: "https://ia800307.us.archive.org/14/items/electricsheep-flock-244-32500-9/00244%3D32649%3D22645%3D23652_512kb.mp4") {
    let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: mediaURL);
    self.webView.load(request)
}
```

Obj-C:

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ia800307.us.archive.org/14/items/electricsheep-flock-244-32500-9/00244%3D32649%3D22645%3D23652_512kb.mp4"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mediaURL]
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```